# Sample size calculation for correlated eye data

Tags: sample-size, cluster-sample

What formula or software package can be used for sample size caculations for correlated eye data? An observational study is being conducted in which participants that have two normal eyes and participants that have a clinical condition in one eye and another clinical condition in the second eye are being recruited. So I have the following groups (case-control sampling design with 3 groups):

**Group A** : participants with two normal eyes (both eyes are included)

**Group B** : eyes with a clinical condition in one eye

**Group C** : eyes with a clinical condition in the other eye

In **Group A**, both eyes of participants are included, so these eyes will be correlated. In **Group B and C** both eyes are assessed and then placed into groups **B and C**, so these groups are also correlated.

The aim of the study is to assess a clinically meaningful difference in a continuous outcome between the three groups, which sample size formula is appropriate here; i) if the outcome is continuous normal, ii) if the outcome is continuous non-normal. Power analysis for the ANOVA model may have been appropriate if the groups were independent, but as we are dealing with correlated eye data it's not clear which sample size formula should be used.

Comment: If you assume each person only contributes one eye, your power will be guaranteed to be underestimated (or correct). If you do anything else your power might be overestimated, so I would take the conservative approach and assume one eye per person.

Comment: Do you mean that if I assume that the groups are independent, when they are not, the power will be underestimated (or correct)?  Doesn't this depend on whether the two eyes are assigned to the same participant group. Comparing groups B and C with paired eye design (one eye in group B and other in group C) will underestimate the power if we ignore inter-eye correlation. However, comparing groups A and B (where two eyes of same person is in group A, so group A eyes correlated), I think the power may be overestimated?

Comment: No. If two eyes are independent, they contribute two data points. If they are perfectly correlated, they contribute one. So two eyes in one person contribute between 1 and 2 to the effective sample size. It's hard to know what that is, so if we assume it's 1, we won't overestimate power.

Comment: @JeremyMiles. Thanks I think I understand the rationale now. But my reasoning was based on something I read in published by the american academy of ophthalmology: Characteristics of Design and Analysis of Ophthalmic Randomized Controlled Trials
Dong, Ruiqi et al.
Ophthalmology Science, Volume 3, Issue 2, 100266 https://www.ophthalmologyscience.org/article/S2666-9145(22)00155-5/fulltext#secsectitle0110

Comment: @JeremyMiles. In the discussion it says: "The impact
of intereye correlation on sample size and power of trials
with 2-eye design depends on whether 2 eyes of a participant are assigned to the same treatment group or not. If 2 eyes of a participant are in the same treatment group (e.g., systemic treatment), ignoring the intereye correlation will
underestimate the sample size (or overestimate the power). If 2 eyes of a participant are in 2 different treatment groups, ignoring the intereye correlation will overestimate the sample size (or underestimate the power)."

Comment: I that that is n is the number of eyes not number of people.

Comment: @JeremyMiles: sorry not sure I understood

Comment: Is there a difference between B and C? Does C mean both eyes have the condition?

Comment: Is it correct to use the stata command power twomeans, cluster for this scenario for comparison of group A and B. It allows cluster sizes of both groups to be specified, which can be set as 2 and 1 respectively. As group A has two (both) normal eyes from a participant and group B with 1 eye of the patient.

Comment: @JeremyMiles: B and C are correlated, they are pairs of eyes. So a participant with one conidition in one eye (B) and a second clinical condition in the other eye (C) will be included in the analysis. So they are eyes from the same participant, analysed in 2 different groups based on the clinical condition they present with. Only eyes that fall into these two groups are included. Group A are participants with two normal eyes (both eyes will be included).